# My JScrollPane scrolls to the antepenultimate row of my JTable, and not to the last row

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, vertical-scrolling

as I described in title, my java method doesn't vertically scroll my jtable, to the last inserted row. That's (I think) because row isn't shown when my programatically scrolling code (as follows) is executed:

```
private void message(String text) { 
    infoTableModel.addRow(new Object[] { text });   
    infoScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar()
       .setValue(infoScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum()); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Better to use `JTable.scrollRectToVisible`:

```
table.scrollRectToVisible(table.getCellRect(table.getRowCount() - 1, 0, true));
```

Comment: @user1189104 worksforme using your code snippet (on the EDT!) Seeing your answer, a base issue here seems to be that we didn't see enough of your code to allow reasonable help :-) So next time, please show an SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 1):

Here is a functional solution, which is also based in my theory, but i couldn't solve by myself.

[How to scroll to last row in a JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890282/howto-to-scroll-to-last-row-on-jtable)

Thanks for all of your help.

Good Luck!

Comment: see my comment to the referenced answer

Comment: 2nd) posted code was enought if you know what i am speaking about.