# JTable's scroll doesn't move to the bottom when rows added

Tags: java, swing

How to scroll to last row of JTable automatically? I searched google few times, but I couldn't find solution.

```
        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {"aaaaa", "bbbb", "cccc", "dddd"},
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));

    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);
    jTable1.scrollRectToVisible(jTable1.getCellRect(jTable1.getRowCount()-1, 0, false));
```

This avobe is part of my source. I'm adding the row in another class there is no problem to adding data. the scroll is fixed on the top of row. How can I able to solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to scroll to last row in a JTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890282/how-to-scroll-to-last-row-in-a-jtable)

Comment: @jzd I red that already, the situation is diffrent. My scroll doesn't move at all.

Comment: Try to just instantiate the scroll bar with jtable instead of setting the viewport

`JScollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(jTable1);`

Comment: @peeskillet Unfortunatelly, It doesn't work. I just changed `jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);` to `jScollPane1 = new JScrollPane(jTable1);`. (JScrollPane already decalred.) Anything I missed? Thank you.

Comment: Did you add the scrollpane to the container and not accidently the table?

Comment: @peeskillet Could you check my gui code? [Click](http://ideone.com/4r0g2r)

Comment: @camickr Thank you so much. now It works. Thank you. Please answer question, I'll choose it. many people will not stuck in same situation. Thank you.

Comment: @JuntaeKim do you update the scroll position every time you add a row, or just once?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm adding the row in another class -

When you are finished adding the row then the `scrollRectToVisible()` method should be wrapped in a `SwingUtitlities.invokeLater()`.